# Creating complementary graph from GIS data (e.g., shapefiles)

Tags: qgis, graph, shape-area

I am new to GIS.

I have some data about shapes, e.g., voting-districts, in several formats such as WMS, JSON, SHP. I want to create a graph (e.g., graphML) such that each district corresponds to a node, and edges indicate that two districts share a border. The nodes should be located in the "mass-point" of a district and edges should be associated with the distance between the nodes. Something like the red graph below.

[image]

Nodes should further store some properties, e.g., longitude, latitude, custom-data.

What are efficient ways to achieve this?

Let me know the pros and cons of your suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. We don't deal in suggestions here, only in solutions, and we certainly wont defend them. Please show what research you did so far, and with which task of youre process you're actually stuck. Also add the software you're working with.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I am at the very beginning, and loaded the data into QGIS. I tried to find some functions therein to achieve the described task, but this seems hopeless. I was hoping that an experienced user can point me to a promising direction but it seems this is the wrong forum then. Sorry again.

Comment: I suggest you break down your workflow into single tasks and do some research on them. If you're stuck, come back and ask a specific question like "how do I get centroids from my polygons" (hint: this was a hint), instead of such a broad question like "how do I get density values from my polygons".